# yajra v8.x jquery datatables how to receive collection from controller on laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, collections, datatables, yajra-datatable

1.
a.blade.php

```
submit a form 
action="a_1"
```

2. web.php

   Route::get('a_1', 'CodoController@a_1');
3. CodoController

   ```
    public function a_1(Request $request)
   {
        $search = $request->all();
        $result=DB:query()
                ->select...
                ->get();

     return view(b_1)
        ->with('result',$result);
    }
   ```
4. b_1.blade.php

   ```
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="users-table">
           <thead>
               <tr>
                   <td>Id</td>
                   <td>Name</td>
                </tr>
           </thead>
       </table>


   <script>
   $(function() {
       $('#users-table').DataTable({
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax:?????<-----How to write this place to receive the $result collection?
           columns: [
               { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
               { data: 'name', name: 'name' }
               ......
           ]
       });
   });
   ```

I don't understand the example
[image]

Is the Route:: class? can use on the controller?
and how can I write the script on the ajax:???? place.
I try to write these into the Codocontroller

```
use DataTables;

public function a_1(Request $request)
{
     $search = $request->all();
     $result=DB:query()
             ->select...
             ->get();

Route::get('b_1', function() {

      return DataTables::collection($result)->toJson();
});
```

Can route write on the controller? I got the error is

```
Class Route cannot find.
```

and if it is right usage .

the b_1.blade.php view below script  how to receive the collection?

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#users-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax:?????<-----How to write this place to receive the $result collection?
            columns: [
                { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
                { data: 'name', name: 'name' }
                ......
            ]
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ajax` property, basically you just set the `ajax call` parameters to get your info.

For example

```
ajax: {
    url: my_url_path,
    data: function(d){
        d.param1 = some_val_1
        d.param2 = some_val_2
    },
}
```

where `URL` is the route where you get your JSON data and `data` is the request parameters .

Above example would create a request URL like this:

`http://my_url_path?param1=some_val_1&param2=some_val_2`

In your case it would be something similar to:

```
ajax: {
    url: '{{url("user-data")}}'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! But the usage of yajra jquery datatables seems different~ https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/engine-collection